# express attr_accessor in the long classic way of writing setter and getter methods?

Tags: ruby

How can i express the attributes methods using normal method styles (the
long coding way) to define them?

```
attr_accessor :name
attr_writer :name
attr_reader :legs, :arms
```

My own try is below. If I'm wrong, then correct it for me by re-typing
it.

My answer is:

```
  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def name=(legs,arms)
    @name = legs, arms
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
```

Comment: Having `attr_accessor` & `attr_writer`/`attr_reader` for the same attribute is redundant since `attr_accessor` is equivalent to calling both `attr_writer` & `attr_reader`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `@name` for a few different tasks in your re-written version. Sometimes it stores the name, and sometimes it stores a tuple of `legs` and `arms`.

What you really want is the far more verbose:

```
def name=(name)
  @name = name
end

def name()
  @name
end

def legs()
  @legs
end

def arms()
  @arms
end
```

It's a good thing you never want to assign to `legs` or `arms`, because that'd be two more pointless methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try to re-write this code and tell me if it is correct :)  I'll write an answer so i can copy and paste my code.

Comment: Thank you i got that done. I was watching Lynda.com script building, when the instructor started the actual program coding, i felt that none of these attr  or methods or hashes i learned were there inside, looked like a totally different language. can you tell me how to write a simple command line script to allow user to input restaurant name and its type and average price? and then get return values for these as well as ability to search for the added restaurants without saving or storing any of the info to any file only using the memory on the computer for one session use?

Comment: That's a much larger question than is well suited to a comment. Break your larger problem into smaller problems: (a) get input from the user (b) write output to the user (c) store data for a restaurant into a class or tuple (d) save restaurant data in an array of your class or tuple (e) retrieve restaurant data from your array of class or tuple. Nearly every problem can be improved by breaking it into smaller pieces.